# Как сделать задержку в анимации?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, блок

Добрый день!
Как сделать задержку в анимации, а именно когда убираешь курсор мыши с блока, чтобы блок возвращался в исходное положение не сразу, а спустя определенный промежуток времени.

```
<div class="div1">Block1</div>
.div { 
    background-color:#ccc; 
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid #000;
 }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".div1").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).animate({ 
                width: 500
                }, 
                {duration:300, queue: false} 
            )
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).animate({
                width: "200px"
                }, 
                {duration:300, queue: false} 
            )
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы блок возвращался в исходное положение не сразу, а спустя определенный промежуток времени, можно блок кода поместить в `setTimeout`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".div1").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).animate({ 
                width: 500
                }, 
                {duration:300, queue: false} 
            )
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
          $this = this;
          
          setTimeout(function () {
            $($this).animate({
                width: "200px"
                }, 
                {duration:300, queue: false} 
            )            
          }, 1000);
          
          
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.div1 { 
    background-color:#ccc; 
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid #000;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">Block1</div>
```

Comment: @LADYX не наблюдаю такой проблемы. тыкал тыкал не протыкал) .... может быть сий код корреллирует где-то еще с чем-то у вас на страницу

Comment: @LADYX К сожалению не могу подсказать пока что. Открыл оперу 35 - все работает. В хроме работает. Опера 35 тоже на вебките как хром.....в IE 10 и FF43 не смог добиться глюка......Надо видео снять)))